# Standardised rates

Tags: standardization, regression-strategies

I'm having trouble understanding the common practice of standardisation in ecological studies involving mortality/incident rates.

Based on [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1360973) by Jeffrey Milyo and Jennifer M Mellor advocates using age as a independent variable in the model rather than using age-standardised rates. In order to reduce bias.

However almost all the papers I've read so far use age-standardised rates.

Which method should be used in modelling?

Are there any similar papers that discuss and critiques either method?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm asking which model is a better choice,
Let's say for incident rate I:

- Where AGE is an independent variable

  $I_s = \beta_1X_s + \sum_k(\gamma_kAGE_{ki}) + U_s$
- Where the dependent variable I is standardised for AGE:

  $I_{si} = \beta_1X_s +U_s $

Comment: ¿Does "age-standardization" involve something more than converting the ages to z-scores based on the sample?

Comment: Age-standardization doesn't involve conversion to z-scores.

Bsaically: ASR = crude rate * standard population /100,000